# Ошибка в терминале PowerShell: Имя "vue" не распознано как имя командлета

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-cli, ecmascript

Установил пакет @vue-cli согласно документации. При вызове команды vue create <project_name> в терминале ошибка:
*Имя "vue" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или в
ыполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а также наличие и
правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.*

В списке глобально установленных пакетов @vue-cli указан как установленный. Не силен в командах и ошибках терминала. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Для исправления ошибки нужно настроить переменную окружения "Path" (в моем случае текущего пользователя) указав в ней путь до глобально установленных пакетов (путей переменная может содержать несколько). Просмотреть этот путь можно вызвав команду npm list -g --depth=0